# How do heteromorphisms arising from constant functors work?

Tags: category-theory

I've been trying to understand how to properly reason about heteromorphisms, and I've run into a conceptual problem.

In [Mac Lane, Bourbaki, and Adjoints: A Heteromorphic Retrospective](http://www.ellerman.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Maclane-Bourbaki-Redux.pdf), it's stated, on page 13 that colimits arise from the universal mapping property;

$\text{Het}(d, c) \simeq \text{Hom}(\text{colim}\ d, c)$, where $c \in C$ and $d \in C^J$, where $J$ is our diagram.

This means that each heteromorphism from $d$ to $c$ should give rise to some morphism out of the colimit.

According to the [nlab page on  profunctors](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/profunctor), ordinary functors $F : C \to D$ give rise to the profunctor $D(1, F)(d, c) \simeq D(d, F(c))$ going from $c$ in $C$ to $d$ in $D$.

Here's my actual problem. The interval category has a coproduct (which acts just like disjunction in boolean logic). If all of this is true, then I should be able to derive some of its equations from this perspective. In particular, I should be able to derive all its properties from;

$\text{Het}(
\lambda x.\text{if}(x, a, b), c) \simeq \text{Hom}(a + b, c)$

I can derive some from listing out the functors from $I^\mathbb{B}$ to $I$. There are four obvious ones, $p \mapsto p(0_\mathbb{B})$, $p \mapsto p(1_\mathbb{B})$, $p \mapsto 0_I$, $p \mapsto 1_I$. Each gives rise to some profunctor. My issue rests with the constant functors. Consider the profunctor $D(1, p \mapsto 1_I)(0_I, c) \simeq D(0_I, 1_I)$. This tells us that a heteromorphism from $c$ to $0_I$ exists whenever there is a morphism from $0_I$ to $1_I$, but there always exists such a morphism, by the definition of the interval category. This gives us $\text{Het}(\lambda x.\text{if}(x, a, b), 0_I)$. By the universal mapping property, we then conclude a  $\text{Hom}(a + b,0_I)$, so $a + b = 0_I$ for all $a$ and $b$, since $0_I$ is initial, but this is obviously wrong.

I'm clearly missing something about how to properly reason with heteromorphisms. If anyone can tell me what my issue is, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Could you clarify your notation? What is $\mathbb B$? What is $I$?

Comment: $\mathbb{B}$ is the discrete category with two objects, e.g. the booleans, the diagram which gives rise to the product and coproduct. $I$ is the interval category.

Comment: So I guess that you meant $I$ for $D$ in the question above.

Comment: Try explaining a little bit more what *this gives us $Het(\lambda x.if(x,a,b),0_I)$* means, especially what is the connection with the profunctor defined before.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I mean $I$ for $D$. I can see that looks a bit confusing.

Comment: As for how we get $\text{Het}(\lambda x. \text{if}(x,a,b),0_I)$, what I mean is that we get an element of that het-set from the fact that we have an element of $D(1, p \mapsto 1_I)(0_I, \lambda x. \text{if}(x,a,b)) \simeq D(0_I, 1_I) \simeq \text{Hom}_I(0_I, 1_I)$. The later element is the definitional morphism from $0_I$ to $1_I$ in $I$.

Comment: The reason we get this is because any functor $F : I^\mathbb{B} \to I$ should induce a profunctor $D(1, F) : I^{op} \times I^\mathbb{B} \to Set$, which on input $(i, f)$ gets us the set $D(1, F)(i, f) \simeq \text{Hom}_I(i, F(f))$. If that hom-set has an element, then we can conclude that the het-set which evaluates to it also has that element as well.

Comment: Just in case, I should clarify that anything in the codomain of a profunctor is a het-set. I might mix up terminology on this, failing to properly differentiate the two. For example $\text{Hom} : C^{op} \times C \to Set$ is an example of a profunctor, where it's output on two inputs, $\text{Hom}(a,b) : Set$ would be an example of a het-set. In general, a profunctor will be something $W : D^{op} \times C \to Set$, with any input $W(d, c) : Set$ being a het-set, and any element of that set being a heteromorphism.

Comment: I can't tell if you're confused on this point or not, but different profunctors $W_1$ and $W_2$ determine different *kinds* of heteromorphisms, because they may give different sets $W_1(d,c)$ and $W_2(d,c)$ and because they may determine different ways of composing heteromorphisms with homomorphisms in $\mathrm{Hom}_C(c,c')$ and in $\mathrm{Hom}_D(d',d)$. The relationship between the coproduct and heteromorphisms is only between the coproduct and a particular *kind* of heteromorphisms: namely $W((a,b),c)$ being the set of cocones from $a$ and $b$ with the "obvious" component-wise compositions.

Comment: That profunctor $W((a,b),c)$ can also be described as $\mathrm{Hom}_{C^{\mathbb B}}(((a,b),\Delta c)$ where $C^{\mathbb B}\xleftarrow{\Delta}C$ is the diagonal functor from $C$ to $C^{\mathbb B}$. This is the one thing that the paper you linked to sweeps under the rug: how do we *construct* het-sets/profunctors which express the universal properties we are interested in?

Comment: @Vladimir Sotirov     I'm aware of what you're referring to. Maybe what you're talking about hasn't completely sunk in, and that's where my confusion lies. I am aware of the adjoint characterization of limits and colimits. The problem I put in my original question was derived from one using that characterization. One thing I don't quite understand is why $W((a,b),c)$ consists of cocones, rather than something else (without deriving that fact from the diagonal). Maybe that's what you're asking, in which case that's what I want to know as well.

Comment: What's your definition of $a+b$? Whatever it is, what you'd have to do is analyze what $W((a,b),c)$ would have to be in order for $\mathrm{Hom}(a+b,c)$ to satisfy $W((a,b),c)\cong\mathrm{Hom}(a+b,c)$. Since for me the definition of $a+b$ is that it is a universal cocone on $a$ and $b$, the fact that the relevant profunctor is the profunctor of cocones on $a$ and $b$ is immediate, but maybe you're using some other definition. Note that I am not saying that $W((a,b),c)$ *has* to be given by the diagonal functor, I'm only saying that it *can be*.

Comment: I think I was having a sort of chicken and egg confusion in my head, assuming that something about the heteromorphism definition should lead to the cocone characterization. Reading back, and with Giorgio's answer in retrospect, it's clear that I'm reversing things. The cocones are supposed to be used to specify what we mean, and both the diagonal and heteromorphism definitions utilize cocones to state this formally. At least, that's the answer I've come to. If I'm still confused about something, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing up a lot of things in a bad way.

It is true that for each functor $F \colon I^{\mathbb B} \to I$ you can get a profunctor $I(F(-),-) \colon {I^\mathbb{B}}^\text{op} \times I \to \mathbf{Set}$ and you can reguard such profunctor as an $\text{Het}_F(-,-) \colon {I^\mathbb{B}}^\text{op} \times I \to \mathbf{Set}$, that for each functor $p \in \colon I^\mathbb{B} \to I$ and each object $c \in I$ gives you a set of heterogeneus morphisms $\text{Het}_F(p,c)$.

What is not true is that for every such $F$ you get a natural isomorphism 
$$\text{Het}_{F}(p,c) \cong I(\text{colim}\ p,c)\ .$$

In particular this does not work in the case at hand where, if I am not mistaken, you are choosing $F$ to be the constant functor sending every diagram in $I^{\mathbb B}$ to the object $0_I$.

In this case you have the natural isomorphism 
$$\text{Het}_F(p,c) \cong I(0_i, c)$$
(the second profunctor is constant in $p$). 
As you noted clearly for $p=\lambda x. if(x,0,1) \in I^\mathbb{B}$ 
you have that $\text{colim}\ p=1_I \ne 0_I$. This proves exactly that not for every $F$ the profunctor $\text{Het}_F$ allows to define/retrive colimits, you have choose whisely the functor.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I think this answers my original question. I now have new ones brought up by my discussions with you and Vladimir, but for the purposes of this post, you've addressed my original issue.

Comment: @NaoAar do you mind me asking what are these questions? :)

Comment: Most are conceptual questions about how one would go about doing some specific thing. For example, how would I construct a heteromorphism for a profunctor which was not representable by a functor? What are the formal rules for constructing and manipulating heteromorphisms? And also Vladimir's question, "how do we construct het-sets/profunctors which express the universal properties we are interested in?" What I'd also like is an extended source on the topic that goes into more detail than Ellerman's work without being so general and example-free as the nlab page.

Comment: I also think some of these questions are better answered by myself (at least until I feel stuck), so I'll mull them over rather than requesting an answer right now.

Comment: @NaoAar Sounds like a great plan. ;)